# Celerybeat Schedule tasks twice a day in different hours

Tags: django, celery, cron, django-celery

I have Django project and I am trying to setup a celery tasks scheduler in CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE.

I need to run a task twice a day, first one at 8:55 and the second one at 17:15.

I know I can run it with same minute like:

```
'schedule': crontab(hour='9,17', minute=0, day_of_week='mon,thu')
```

But I don't know how to setup each hour with the right minute.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
crontab(minute="55,15", hour="8,17", day_of_week='*',
        day_of_month='*', month_of_year='*')
```

Comment: I will try it and let you know.
So basically I can create a list separated in comma in the hours and minutes and the crontab will combine them together in the right order?
8:55 & 17:15. and not 8:55, 8:15, 17:55, 17:15

Comment: No, this would run at 8:15, 8:55, 17:15, 17:55.

Answer (score 0):

[@denvaar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37741024/3325322) seems like it would run at 8:15, 8:55, 17:15, 17:55.

If that doesn't work as you want, I would just schedule it in two different lines:

```
crontab(minute="55", hour="8", day_of_week='*', day_of_month='*', month_of_year='*')
crontab(minute="15", hour="17", day_of_week='*', day_of_month='*', month_of_year='*')
```

Comment: I would like to see more detail of how this was done. If you create two crontab schedules for the same task, because they are the same task, the 2nd will overwrite the first inside celery. Someone else explained: "task_name is a unique index. In table periodictask, a task-name can be there only once."